# Trying to sort objects in an arraylist by a property but the objects don't always sort properly

Tags: java, sorting

I have four classes but they're just templates so I'll only post my main class (I have overridden toString for each). The sort method is at the bottom. Everything else is fine (more or less) with my code, but when I create the objects in the array and then go to sort them (by a string value called uid) sometimes one or two of them will be out of order. How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

enum ClassStanding{FRESHMAN,SOPHOMORE,JUNIOR,SENIOR,UNKNOWN,MASTERS_STUDIES,PHD_STUDIES};
enum Major{CS,CEG,EE,ISE,BME,ME,MET,UNKNOWN};
enum StudentType{UNDERGRADUATE,GRADUATE,UNDECLARED};

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter;
    boolean continueInput;
    int contCounter;
    do {
        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter what you want to do-ADD, REMOVE, SORT, LIST, or SAVE: ");
            switch (stdin.next().toLowerCase()) {
                case "add":
                    add(stdin, studentList);
                    counter = 0;
                    break;
                case "remove":
                    remove(studentList, stdin);
                    counter = 0;
                    break;
                case "list":
                    list(studentList);
                    counter = 0;
                    break;
                case "save":
                    String fileName = getFileName(stdin);
                    save(fileName, studentList);
                    counter = 0;
                    break;
                case "sort":
                    counter = 0;
                    sort(studentList);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Improper input, please enter only ADD, REMOVE, LIST, or SAVE.");
                    counter = 1;
            }
        } while (counter == 1);
        do {
            System.out.print("\nDo you want to continue? Yes or no: ");
            switch (stdin.next().toLowerCase()) {
                case "yes":
                    contCounter = 0;
                    continueInput = true;
                    break;
                case "no":
                    contCounter = 0;
                    continueInput = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    contCounter = 1;
                    continueInput = false;
                    System.out.print("\nPlease only enter 'yes' or 'no'.");
            }
        } while (contCounter == 1);
    } while (continueInput);
} // end main method

public static void add(Scanner stdin, ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String uid;
    StudentType studentType;
    ClassStanding studentClassStanding;
    Major major;
    double overallGPA;
    double majorGPA;
    String majorProfessor;
    boolean thesisOption;
    System.out.print("Please enter the student's first name: ");
    String tempName = stdin.next();
    firstName = checkName(tempName);
    System.out.print("Please enter the student's last name: ");
    tempName = stdin.next();
    lastName = checkName(tempName);
    System.out.println("Please enter the student's UID in the format 'U####' or 'U#####': ");
    String tempUID = stdin.next();
    uid = checkUID(tempUID).toUpperCase();
    int count;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter the student's status as UNDECLARED, UNDERGRADUATE, or GRADUATE: ");
        switch (stdin.next().toUpperCase()) {
            case "UNDECLARED":
                studentType = StudentType.UNDECLARED;
                studentClassStanding = setStudentClassStanding(studentType);
                count = 0;
                Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName,
                        uid, studentType, studentClassStanding);
                studentList.add(student);
                break;
            case "UNDERGRADUATE":
                studentType = StudentType.UNDERGRADUATE;
                major = setMajor();
                studentClassStanding = setStudentClassStanding(studentType);
                System.out.println("Enter the student's overall GPA below.");
                overallGPA = setGPA();
                System.out.println("Enter the student's major GPA below.");
                majorGPA = setGPA();
                count = 0;
                UnderGraduate underGraduate = new UnderGraduate(firstName, lastName, uid, studentType,
                        studentClassStanding, major, overallGPA, majorGPA);
                studentList.add(underGraduate);
                break;
            case "GRADUATE":
                studentType = StudentType.GRADUATE;
                studentClassStanding = setStudentClassStanding(studentType);
                majorProfessor = setMajorProfessor();
                thesisOption = setThesisOption();
                count = 0;
                Graduate graduate = new Graduate(firstName, lastName, uid, studentType,
                        studentClassStanding, majorProfessor, thesisOption);
                studentList.add(graduate);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter either Undeclared, Undergraduate, or Graduate only.");
                count = 1;
        }
    } while (count == 1);
} // end add method

public static String checkName(String tempName) {
    int a = 1;
    String name1;        
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        name1 = tempName; // hold the value of firstName in name1
        for (int i = 0; i < tempName.length(); i++) { // loop to check input consists of letters (is a name)
            if (!Character.isLetter(tempName.charAt(i))) { // if non-letters detected, ensure this was intentional
                System.out.println("Please ensure you've entered the correct name. Re-enter the name or enter 'continue' to proceed: ");
                tempName = scanner.nextLine();
                if (tempName.equalsIgnoreCase("continue")) { // if user enters "continue", use original input
                    a = 0;
                    tempName = name1; // pass name1 value to firstName
                    break;
                } else {
                    a = 1; // continue prompting for firstName
                }
            } else { // accept input
                a = 0;
            }
        }
    } while (a == 1); // loop to ensure proper input
    return tempName;
} // end checkName method

public static String checkUID(String tempUID) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    do {
        if (tempUID.charAt(0) == 'U' || tempUID.charAt(0) == 'u') {
            if (tempUID.length() == 6 || tempUID.length() == 5) {
                a = 0;
            } else {
                a = 1;
                System.out.print("Please ensure input is in the form of U#### or U#####. Please re-enter the UID: ");
                tempUID = scan.next();
            }
        } else {
                a = 1;
                System.out.print("Please ensure input is in the form of U#### or U#####. Please re-enter the UID: ");
                tempUID = scan.next();
        }
    } while (a == 1);
    return tempUID;
} // end checkUID method

public static ClassStanding setStudentClassStanding(StudentType studentType) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count;
    ClassStanding studentTempClassStanding = null;
    do {
        if (studentType == StudentType.UNDECLARED || studentType == StudentType.UNDERGRADUATE) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the student's class standing as either Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior, or Unknown: ");
        switch (scan.next().toUpperCase()) {
            case "FRESHMAN":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.FRESHMAN;
                count = 0;
                break;
            case "SOPHOMORE":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.SOPHOMORE;
                count = 0;
                break;
            case "JUNIOR":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.JUNIOR;
                count = 0;
                break;
            case "SENIOR":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.SENIOR;
                count = 0;
                break;
            case "UNKNOWN":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.UNKNOWN;
                count = 0;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter only Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior, or Unknown.");
                count = 1;
        } 
        } else {
                System.out.print("Please enter the student's class standing as either 'Masters' for Masters Studies or 'PhD' for PhD Studies: ");
                switch (scan.next().toUpperCase()) {
                    case "MASTERS": studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.MASTERS_STUDIES; count = 0; break;
                    case "PHD": studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.PHD_STUDIES; count = 0; break;
                    default: System.out.println("Please enter only 'Masters' or 'PhD'.");
                count = 1;
                }
                }
    } while (count == 1);
    return studentTempClassStanding;
} // end setStudentClassStanding method

public static Major setMajor() {
    Major tempMaj = null;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter the student's major as either CS, CEG, EE, ISE, BME, ME, MET, or Unknown: ");
        switch (s.next().toUpperCase()) {
            case "CS":
                tempMaj = Major.CS;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "CEG":
                tempMaj = Major.CEG;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "EE":
                tempMaj = Major.EE;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "ISE":
                tempMaj = Major.ISE;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "BME":
                tempMaj = Major.BME;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "ME":
                tempMaj = Major.ME;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "MET":
                tempMaj = Major.MET;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "UNKOWN":
                tempMaj = Major.UNKNOWN;
                c = 0;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter only the specified values. ");
                c = 1;
        }
    } while (c == 1);
    return tempMaj;
} // end setMajor method

public static double setGPA() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    double gpa;
    int a;
    do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Please enter the student's GPA: ");
                gpa = s.nextDouble();// read in the gpa
                if (gpa < 0.0 || gpa > 4.0) { // ensure the gpa is in the correct range
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a positive value between 0.0 and 4.0.");
                    a = 1;
                } else {
                    a = 0;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) { //catch any exceptions, prompt for correct input
                a = 1;
                gpa = 0.0;
                System.out.println("Sorry, please enter a double value.");
                s.nextLine(); // skip the last input
            }
        } while (a == 1 || gpa < 0.0 || gpa > 4.0); //loop while gpa is negative or incorrect input is received
    return gpa;
} // end setGPA method

private static String setMajorProfessor() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String prof;
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the major professor: ");
    String tempName = s.nextLine();
    prof = checkName(tempName);
    return prof;
} // end setMajorProfessor method

private static boolean setThesisOption() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean thesis = false;
    int a;
    do {
    System.out.print("Please enter 'yes' if a thesis will be written, otherwise enter 'no': ");
    switch (s.next().toUpperCase()) {
        case "YES": thesis = true; a = 0; break;
        case "NO": thesis = false; a = 0; break;
        default: System.out.println("Please enter only 'yes' or 'no'."); a = 1;
    }
    } while (a == 1);
    return thesis;
} // end setThesisOption method

private static void list(ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(studentList.get(i).toString());
    }
} // end list method

public static String getFileName(Scanner stdin) {
    System.out.print("Please enter the file name: "); // Prompt for input
    String fileString = stdin.next();
    return fileString; // Pass the fileString var to the main method
}//end of getFileName method

private static void save(String fileName, ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
    int a; // create a counter
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName); // Create a printwriter 
            for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
                writer.print(studentList.get(i).toString() + "\n"); //Print the arraylist to file
            }
            writer.close(); //Close the printwriter and save the file
            a = 0;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { // Catch any exceptions
            System.out.println("The file could not be found, please re-enter the file name: "); // get new file name if an exception is thrown
            fileName = stdin.nextLine();
            a = 1;
        }
    } while (a == 1); // loop while exceptions are thrown
    System.out.println("All information has been saved at " + fileName); // output that the arraylist has been saved in the specified file
    // Make the following its own method
    System.out.print("Would you like to read the contents of the file? Yes or no: ");
    int b;
    do {
    switch (stdin.next().toLowerCase()) {
        case "yes": readFromFile(fileName); b = 0; break;
        case "no": b = 0; break;
        default: System.out.println("Please enter only yes or no."); b = 1;
    }
    } while (b == 1);
} // end save method

private static void remove(ArrayList<Student> studentList, Scanner stdin) {
    System.out.print("Please enter the UID of the student to be removed: ");
    String tempUID = stdin.next();
    String uidRemove = checkUID(tempUID);
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
        if ((studentList.get(i).getUid()).equalsIgnoreCase(uidRemove)) {
            studentList.remove(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The student with UID " + uidRemove + " has been removed.");
} // end remove method

private static void sort(ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
    String uidLessU1;
    String uidLessU2;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
        uidLessU1 = (studentList.get(i).getUid()).substring(1, studentList.get(i).getUid().length());
        for (int j = 0; j < studentList.size(); j++) {
            uidLessU2 = (studentList.get(j).getUid()).substring(1, studentList.get(j).getUid().length());
            if (Integer.parseInt(uidLessU1) < Integer.parseInt(uidLessU2)) {
                Student hold = studentList.get(i);
                studentList.set(i, studentList.get(j));
                studentList.set(j, hold);
            }
        }
    }
} // end sort method

private static void readFromFile(String fileName) {
    System.out.println("The contents of " + fileName + " as read from NotePad: ");
    try {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); //Create a scanner
        while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {    //Loop to read the file
            String fromFile = fileReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(fromFile); //Output the file contents
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { //Catch any exceptions
        System.out.println("Exception caught");
    }
} // end readFromFile method
} // end main class
```

A sample of the problem would be (at this point I've already entered all the values instantiating the objects):

```
Do you want to continue? Yes or no: yes
Please enter what you want to do-ADD, REMOVE, SORT, LIST, or SAVE: list

Student s w whose UID is U3333 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student p o whose UID is U1111 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student p u whose UID is U44444 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student w e whose UID is U4444 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student s r whose UID is U2222 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student s u whose UID is U7777 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student po iu whose UID is U77777 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Do you want to continue? Yes or no: yes
Please enter what you want to do-ADD, REMOVE, SORT, LIST, or SAVE: sort //calls the sort method

Do you want to continue? Yes or no: yes
Please enter what you want to do-ADD, REMOVE, SORT, LIST, or SAVE: list // calls the list method and prints out the arraylist

Student p o whose UID is U1111 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student s r whose UID is U2222 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student s w whose UID is U3333 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student s u whose UID is U7777 is a //why is this out of place?
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student w e whose UID is U4444 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student p u whose UID is U44444 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work. 

Student po iu whose UID is U77777 is a 
UNDECLARED student doing JUNIOR work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make Student implement *Comparable* and then you can do

```
    Collections.sort(studentList);
```